# Android: How to access toolbar from RecyclerViewHolder?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, toolbar

**Question**

How can I access a toolbar and its children from a RecyclerViewHolder?
I want to change the textView in my toolbar_main from RecyclerViewHolder with LongClick.

**What I know**

I know how to access the toolbar from my activty inside onCreate with

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    txtTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    rbSelectAll = (RadioButton)toolbar.findViewById(R.id.rbSelectAll);
    rbSelectAll.setVisibility(GONE);
    txtTitle.setText("Gallerie");
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolders> {

    private List<ItemObject> itemList;
    private Context context;
    private boolean isDir;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<ItemObject> itemList, boolean isDir) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.isDir = isDir;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_list, null);
        RecyclerViewHolders rcv = new RecyclerViewHolders(layoutView, itemList, context);
        return rcv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {

        if(isDir){
            File[] fileNames = null;
            Log.v("Folder: ", itemList.get(position).getName());

            File path = new File(itemList.get(position).getName());
            if(path.exists()){
                fileNames = path.listFiles();
            }

            int i = 0;
            while(fileNames[i].isDirectory()){
                i++;
            }

            Glide.with(context).asBitmap()
                    .load(fileNames[i])
                    .thumbnail(0.2f)
                    .into(holder.countryPhoto);

            holder.selected.setVisibility(GONE);
            holder.albumName.setText(itemList.get(position).getName().substring(itemList.get(position).getName().lastIndexOf("/")+1));
            holder.countImages.setText(""+listFiles(itemList.get(position).getName()).size());

        }else {
            holder.selected.setVisibility(GONE);
            holder.albumName.setVisibility(GONE);
            holder.countImages.setVisibility(GONE);
            Glide.with(context).asBitmap()
                    .load(itemList.get(position).getName())
                    .thumbnail(0.2f)
                    .into(holder.countryPhoto);
        }
    }
}
```

**RecyclerViewHolders.java**

```
public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener{

    public TextView albumName, countImages, txtName;
    public ImageView countryPhoto;
    private List<ItemObject> itemList;
    public RadioButton selected, selectAll;

    public RecyclerViewHolders(View itemView, List<ItemObject> itemList, Context context) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        this.itemList = itemList;

        selected = (RadioButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rbSelected);
        albumName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.albumName);
        countImages = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.countImages);
        countryPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_photo);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked " + getPosition() + " " + itemList.get(getPosition()).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Long Clicked " + getPosition() + " " + itemList.get(getPosition()).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(selected.isChecked()){
            selected.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            selected.setChecked(false);
        }else{
            selected.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            selected.setChecked(true);
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.spicysoftware.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbarPictures"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="8dp"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**toolbar_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#5fb0c9"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: with the help of interface, you can do this

Comment: How about storing the Toolbar reference as attribute in your activity and declare both the RecyclerView adapter and the holder as nested class of your activity? In this way you can easily access the attribute referencing the toolbar.

Comment: Did you try eventbus? It's very easy to use. https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((MainActivity) context).toolbar
```

Or
    ((MainActivity) context).findViewById(R.id.toolbar)

Comment: This isn't the correct way to do this. View code should not directly modify the non related or owned view hold. Think about it this way, children shouldn't tell each other what to do, parents should inform the children what to do. With your solution, your child view is telling another child view what to do. The child view should inform the parent of the event, and allow the parent to tell the child what to do.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Create a class and Interface for RecyclerViewOnItemClick

> RecyclerTouchListener.java

```
public class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener{

    private IOnRecyclerItemClickedListener clicklistener;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recycleView, final IOnRecyclerItemClickedListener clicklistener){

        this.clicklistener=clicklistener;
        gestureDetector=new GestureDetector(context,new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child=recycleView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(),e.getY());
                if(child!=null && clicklistener!=null){
                    clicklistener.onLongClick(child,recycleView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        View child=rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(),e.getY());
        if(child!=null && clicklistener!=null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)){
            clicklistener.onClick(child,rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
}
```

> Interface IOnRecyclerItemClickedListener.java

```
public interface IOnRecyclerItemClickedListener {
    public void onRecyclerItemClick(View view, int position);
    public void onRecyclerItemLongClick(View view,int position);
}
```

Step 2: Implement IOnRecyclerItemClickedListener in your activity

> YourActivity.java

```
public class YourActivity extends Fragment implements IOnRecyclerItemClickedListener{

private Toolbar toolbar;
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        txtTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        rbSelectAll = (RadioButton)toolbar.findViewById(R.id.rbSelectAll);
    rbSelectAll.setVisibility(GONE);
    txtTitle.setText("Gallerie");
    }

@Override
    public void onRecyclerItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
       toolbar.setTitle("Title that you want to display");
    }


    @Override
    public void onRecyclerItemClick(View v) {

        }
    }
}
```

I hope this answer will help you!!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't couple two entirely separate Views. You should define an onLongClick interface that your Activity should implement and you set it on each and every itemView inside of the constructor for your ViewHolder then do your Toolbar functionality.

Comment: I dont get it sorry. Is there any tutorial?

Comment: What you want to do is define an interface with a method that will get called by your list item's onLongClick method and make your Activity implement the interface. You pass a reference of the activity into the RecyclerAdapter which will pass the reference into each ViewHolder constructor where it will get stored as an internal variable. When ever the ViewHolder's onLongClick fires, you call the method that you defined on the interface against the reference passed in to the Constructor. See vivek patel answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use interface to achieve your goal as shown below.

Create an interface.

```
public interface DummyInterface {
    public void doSomethingWithToolbar();
}
```

Then implement this interface on your activity.

```
public class DummyActivity extends Activity implements DummyInterface {
    .
    .
    .
    public void doSomethingWithToolbar() {
        //do something with toolbar
    }
}
```

Then pass the reference of this(activity) when creating recycler view in constructor. Like,

```
new DummyRecyclerView(..., this);
```

Then add a parameter in RecyclerView's constructor. Like,

```
DummyInterface dummy = new DummyInterface();
public DummyRecyclerView(..., DummyInterface d) {
    dummy = d;
}
```

Then pass dummy to the RecyclerViewHolder's constructor and add that to parameter in constructor of RecyclerViewHolder same way we have done from Activity to RecyclerView.
And you can call the method `doSomethingWithToolbar` from RecyclerViewHolder using `dummy.doSomethingWithToolbar()`.